# Two data sets from test with a 95% confidence limit of reproduceability and standard deviation of each data set

Tags: hypothesis-testing

This may have been answered and I'm simply not using the correct search terms to find the answer/thread.  If so i apologize, please point me in the right direction

I have two data sets (3 measurements each)

- A: Mean = 2.2 SD = 0.318 (2.16, 2.12, 2.32)
- B: Mean = 1.8 SD = 0.455 (1.79, 1.98, 1.68)

The test method used to generate this data has a intralaboratory reporducability value of 27.8% of the means.

I am trying to show that these data sets are from the same population (i.e. the change we made had no statistically significant impact on the results).

Looking at means and three sigma, Mean of B is greater than three sigma from mean of A, so unlikely from the same population.

The data sets show a critical ratio of 3.6, again showing these are not from the same population.

[image: Critical ratio:]

A T-Test shows a two tail p value of 0.16, again showing a difference.

The issue I have is none of these take into account the variability of the test method itself.  Should this be the first determination explored, i.e. the means are not more than 27.8% different therefore we can assume the means are from the same population?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is intralaboratory reporducability and why does it matter? What is a critical ratio? T-test $p>\alpha$ means **no** difference.

Comment: Interlaboratory reporducability is the precision of the test method, if the same operator, in the same lab using the same equipment conducts the same test multiple times then it is expected that the means of those test should not vary by greater than 27.8% in this case (With 95% confidence). Critical ratio is a test for central tendency, based on mean and standard error.

Comment: Interlaboratory reporducability does not matter in this case, it is only an added bonus, giving you more power in your tests. How did you calculate this "critical ratio"? Also, the t-test shows no difference, which is not that surprising, given your tiny sample size.

Comment: @user2974951 "A non-significant difference" is crucially different from "no difference."  Aaron Brighton:  I think you have made errors in calculating your standard deviations.

Comment: @rolando2 you're correct, those values are three sigma.

Comment: critical ratio formula added to OP